# Conexão via PHP a uma base de dados SQL Server 2012

Tags: php, c#, sql-server, conexão, banco-de-dados

O meu problema tem algumas variantes:

- Tenho um website construido em joomla, que está alojado num servidor linux.
- O administrador onde tenho alojado o meu website, já me informou que não instalará    nenhuma extensão do php, de forma a não arranjar conflitos nem problemas no servidor
- O módulo php, não contém qualquer extensão de conexão a Sql server (e.g, sqlsrv, mssql)
- Possuo um programa em c#, e a minha base de dados está armazenada na Amazon (SQL Server 2012)

Para resumir, preciso que o meu site se consiga conectar à minha base de dados Sql Server 2012 do meu programa para mostrar no website a informação que lá possuo, podendo também adicionar nova informação, alterá-la etc.

Se alguém souber como fazer essa mesma conexão, tendo em conta as variáveis a que estou sujeito, agradecia imenso.

Comment: Podes sempre ter o PHP também alojado na Amazon, e de lá fazes a conexão a BD. Depois é só *linkar* o PHP do teu *website* com o da Amazon.

Comment: Eu mudaria de servidor, aonde já se viu não instalar as extensões do PHP, isso é privação de um serviço, troque de servidor urgentemente

Comment: Já tentou com [adodb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/#download) ?

Comment: Harry Potter mas o PHP de lá possui os módulos necessários para a conexão a SQL Server?É que se não tiverem volto à mesma situação na qual estou agora.
Jorge B, poderias explicar um pouco melhor a tua ideia?Não entendi muito bem como fazer isso que disseste.
Desde já um obrigado aos 2 pelos comenários

Comment: Perdeu, obrigado pelo comentário. O que me sugeriu é necessário uma instalação do adobd correto?É que eu não estou habilitado a instalar algo, devido às restrições que tenho do administrador do alojamento.

Comment: @Hélder, pelo que diz a documentação basta descompactar os arquivos na pasta do projeto que já funciona. Não tenho o sql server aqui para testar. [exemplo](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/docs-adodb.htm#odbc_mssql)

Comment: Tem possibilidade de criar um webservice? Desta forma, você, a partir de seu website, resgata os dados da base SQLServer no servidor da Amazon por este serviço.

Comment: Você tem a oportunidade para trocar para uma hospedagem windows no mesmo valor? Caso sim você pode tentar a solução  [usada neste link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643988/php-to-sql-server-without-odbc-or-mssql-support)

Comment: @jefersondaniel a solução apresentada nesse link só funciona em windows é?

Comment: @LeoFilipe aconselhame a usar o SOAP?Conhece algum webservice para tal efeito que pretendo já feito?

Comment: @perdeu vou testar a solução indicada por si. Depois darei feedback se resultar.

Comment: @perdeu não funciona mas obrigado na mesma. No fim de descompactar, reparei que para conectar a bd sql server ele recorre à extensão mssql, extensão essa que não está incluída no PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Se no seu host você está limitado para as extensões, eu iria resolver isso usando PHP normal para contectar a um serviço exposto no Amazon.

Seria um WebAPI feito em cima do banco de dados SQL, que o PHP poderia então mandar chamados HTTP a ele e conseguir os dados em XML ou JSON. Assim você consegue `POST` para criar novo recordes, `PUT` para fazer atualizações, `DELETE` para apagar, e `GET` para selecionar.

É uma metodologia bastante comun, chamado de DAL (Data Access Layer, camada de acceso aos dados) ou API (Application Programming Interface).

Comment: mas como faço a conexão com o PHP à base de dados SQL Server?Não consigo entender essa parte, devido às limitações que tenho.

Comment: A minha resposta está dizendo que, já que não consegue fazer uma conexão direto, põe um webservice por cima. O web service vai ter todo direito e acesso ao SQL Server, enquanto o PHP só chama o webservice. Para chamar um webservice em PHP é bastante simples, e para meu entendimento não precisa de extensão.

Comment: irei tentar fazer isso a ver se resolvo a questão.